# Connecting Android Phone With ADB

Tags: android, adb, motorola

I recently bought a new phone (Motorola Electrify) and I'm trying to connect it with ADB but so far without luck. What I did:

- Enable USB debugging on the phone
- Connect phone to my iMac using the USB cable (the display indicates that it's connected)
- Type "./adb devices" to list connected devices

Unfortunately nothing shows up. I even did a adb kill/start-server and I also added "0x22B8" to the adb_usb.ini (even though that shouldn't be necessary).

Can anyone point out what other steps I could take to debug why the device isn't showing up?

Thanks!

Comment: You should install driver first.  Search driver Linux in Android developer website.

Comment: I second what user674199 said, as well. I know I've had to chase down drivers every time I've wanted to use ADB on Windows, be it 7 or Vista (XP once as well), but I haven't had to perform the process on Mac yet.  But following a link from Google's Developer pages to Motorola, yields no Mac or Linux drivers: http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/USB_Drivers/

Comment: You don't need drivers on Mac for connecting with ADB. Please read solution below in case you're interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for your answers above, but I've resolved it myself. For anyone who has the same problem:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15583

has the answer.

It turns out that Motorola has several USB modes. I changed the mode to "USB Mass Storage" and it's working now. I did this by dragging the status bar down and clicking on "USB connection" to manage the USB connection.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else isn't clear, usb debugging must be enabled (at least for a droid mini).

Answer (score 2):

@Joris If you're loading multiple apps on your phone, you might be better off using the MTP mode on your phone (instead of USB Mass Storage) for reasons covered herein - http://www.androidcentral.com/ics-feature-mtp-what-it-why-use-it-and-how-set-it.

p.s: admittedly, this may not be backwards compatible, but hopefully everyone's finally upgrading to ICS and beyond

Answer (score -4):

Step four found at this link may be helpful:

http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/

> **Create an environment variable (Optional)**
>
> Open Terminal
>
> Type cd ~ this will take you to your home directory
>
> Type touch .profile this will create a hidden file named profile
>
> Type open -e .profile this will open the file you just created in
>   TextEdit In the file, type export
>   PATH=${PATH}:/pathToTheAndroidSdkFolder/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools
>
> Save file, close TextEdit, Quit Terminal, and Relaunch Terminal
>
> NOTE: By creating an environment variable you won’t need to cd to the
>   Android/tools folder every time you want to run ADB

Comment: This is not relevant to my question.